# In node.js, how to use node.js and mongodb to store data in multiple levels

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I met a wired problem, that when i use mongodb to store data, some data is missing, which I think it is because of its asynchronous feature

So for this list the timetable, I would use re

/* Here is the a application, in which by using a train_uid and today, 
*/

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
scheduleModel.findByTrainAndTime(train_uid,today,function(err, doc){
    var a = new Object();
    if(err){}
    else{
        if(doc != null)
        {
```

//mongodb database can give me some data about the train_id ,uid

```
        a.train_uid = doc.train_uid;
        a.train_id = train_id;
```

and most importantly a train schedule time table, the train schedule time table is a list ( doc.time_schedule )of json objects like arrival, departure and tiploc.  However, I need to change the tiploc to sanox number, which referenceModel can help find sanox by providing tiploc number.

```
                   //doc.time_schedule
                   // here is to add a array
```

so I use async, for each item in the list, I use referenceModel to query sanox and construct a array - a.timeline to store each b,  at last when async each operation is finished, trainModel is to store a object with an array of sanox object. However when it comes to the mongodb database, only the array of sanox objects are empty, I guess it is because of asynchronous operation, but since I used async , why it doesn't work

```
                    a.train_uid = doc.train_uid;  //works
        a.train_id = train_id;   works
                    a.timeline = []   // doesn't work    
        a.timeline = new Array();                                               
        var b ;
            async.forEachSeries(doc.time_schedule,
              function(item,callback){
                   referenceModel.findStanoxByTicloc(item.tiploc_code,function(err,sanox){ 
                      try{ 
                        b = new Object();
                                            b.sanox = sanox;
                        a.time.push(b);

                      }catch(err2){

                      }
                  });   
                  callback();
              },
              function(err){
                trainModel.createNewTrain(a,function(){}); 

        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: where are you actually writing something into mongo?  I don't see it - I can't even tell where you are getting data from Mongo and where you're writing it back.  Could you maybe include complete code with commentary all above or all below - it's very hard to read the way you have it.

Comment: scheduleModel.findByTrainAndTime,referenceModel.findStanoxByTicloc  and trainModel.createNewTrain

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `callback` after you fire off the asynchronous `find`, but before it actually comes back.  You need to wait until after you've gotten the data to do that.  The following should work better:

```
    async.forEachSeries(doc.time_schedule,
          function(item,callback){
             referenceModel.findStanoxByTicloc(item.tiploc_code,function(err,sanox){ 
                  try{ 
                    b = new Object();
                    b.sanox = sanox;
                    a.time.push(b);

                  }catch(err2){

                  }
                  callback();
              });   
          },
          function(err){
            trainModel.createNewTrain(a,function(){}); 

    }
```

Comment: I thought it should work in that way, but as long as referenceModel find the result for the first or second element in the  doc.time_schedule array, which means that when the forEachSeries not finished and the code will jump to traimModel.createNewTrain(a,function()){}.  I am so confused, asynchronous programming is so problematic for me